# Parse - Updating local DataStore in combination with LiveQuery

Tags: parse-platform

I am writing an Android app using the local data store and LiveQueries. I am facing a problem in the combination of both. When I start the app, I fetch all instances of an entity the current user has access to and save them in the local storage. Additionally, I subscribe to changes of this entity with the same query using a LiveQuery. When such an entity that is changed by cloud code, e.g., gets deleted, the event is properly received in the app. However, the entity as part of the local storage is not deleted. As I have not found anything about this in the documentation or by searching the Internet my question is, if this is normal behavior and if I have to deal with the changes in the local storage manually, e.g., by unpinning the entity in this case. The other possibility is, that it should update, but it does not in my case somehow.

If I have to deal with it manually: What is the best way to replace/update the entity in the local storage, if only an update happens?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you will have to deal with it manually. I'd try to unpin the old object and pin the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I simply do the pinning/unpinning now in every event handler. It really seems, that there is no automatic updating of the local datastore.